# invalid Signature error while uploading Linphone App ipa file to itunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, linphone

We were facing an issue from  one week, but couldn't slove the issue. Can any one help me we appreciate them alot.

while uploading Linphone-iOS ipa file(64-bit source Code) to iTunes through Application loader.

we using
1) mac version 10.10.3.
2) xcode version 6.1.1.

Below is the error we were getting while uploading through Application loader. can you suggest me how we can able to slove the issue. Thanks in advance.

Error Message:
"Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. The binary at path [linphone.app/ImageOptim.sh] contains an invalid signature. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.

For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html”]

Comment: You forgot to mention that you've tried everything the error message suggests?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30793765/503821